# php+MYSQL+Get n rows once

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, count

I have a database that looks like this: (dates are formated with `strtotime`)

```
ID  Date            
1   1338366170000
2   1337761370000
3   1337761370000
4   1337761370000
5   1337156570000
6   1331713370000
7   1331713370000
```

As you can see some entries are from the same date. I would now like to grab each date and the count how often it occurs.

So the end result would look like:

```
Date: 1338366170000
Count: 1

Date: 1337761370000
Count: 3

Date: 1337156570000
Count: 1 

Date: 1331713370000
Count: 2
```

I am currently doing this to get all dates and count each date:

First I grab all rows:

```
$stats      = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM stats_clicks");
```

Now, I think the problems begin when I try to count the entries with same date: I loop through all results and search for each date and count it.

```
foreach($sql->get() as $result){

    //Sum clicks for each date
    $date   = $result["date"];

    $stats  = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM stats_clicks WHERE date = '$date'");
    $count  = count($sql->get());

    echo "Date: $date<br>Count: $count<br><br>";

}
```

The output is:

```
Date: 1338366170000
Count: 1

Date: 1337761370000
Count: 3

Date: 1337761370000
Count: 3

Date: 1337761370000
Count: 3

Date: 1337156570000
Count: 1 

Date: 1331713370000
Count: 2 

Date: 1331713370000
Count: 2
```

How can I avoid outputing each date multiple times, but instead each date only once with the correct count?

Comment: `SELECT *, count(dinstinct date) FROM stats_clicks WHERE date = '$date' group by date` - should do it.

Comment: @Gavin: `count(dinstinct date)` would always return 1 if you have `group by date`

Comment: Well spotted, usually when doing counts, I put a distinct in just in case of multiple entries when joining. Bad habit I know ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `Date`, COUNT(`Date`) as `Count`
FROM stats_clicks
GROUP BY `Date`
```

Result

```
Date    Count
1331713370000   2
1337156570000   1
1337761370000   3
1338366170000   1
```

Comment: I would replace that query with my second query inside the loop, right? I get some weird results, but it must be something else in my code than

Comment: @Andrej no you would replace your entire code with this, this stuff is supposed to be done in the database, not PHP. As in, `$stats = $sql->query( "the query in this answer" )->get()`. Run a `print_r` on that and you'll see it should have already the results in

Comment: Oh, I see. I always wonder how I manage to over-complicate things.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Go with this query. You will get corect count with no repetition.
SELECT date,count(*) FROM stats_clicks GROUP BY date;